# Trying to call useContext outside of a function component

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly use React Context.  I'm hung up on this issue of trying to access the Context from outside the function component.  I'm getting the error:

> Line 9:18:  React Hook "useContext" is called in function "onDragEnd" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Here is my entire Schedule js file:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import OrderColumn from '../ordercolumn/OrderColumn';
import { ScheduleContext } from '../../schedule-context';

const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { destination, source, draggableId } = result;
    const context = useContext(ScheduleContext); // <-- issue is here

    if (!destination) {
        return;
    }

    if (
        destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
        destination.index === source.index
    ) {
        return;
    }

    const column = context.columns[source.droppableId];
    const orderIDs = Array.from(column.orderIDs);
    orderIDs.splice(source.index, 1);
    orderIDs.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);

    const newColumn = {
        ...column,
        orderIDs: orderIDs
    };

    const newColumns = {
        ...context.columns,
        newColumn
    };

    context.setColumns(newColumns);
};

const Schedule = () => {
    const { orders, setOrders, columns, setColumns } = useContext(
        ScheduleContext
    );
    return (
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
            <div className={'full-width'}>
                <h1 className={'text-center'}>Schedule</h1>
                <div className={'lines row no-gutters'}>
                    {columns.map(function(val, index) {
                        if (index === 0) {
                            return (
                                <OrderColumn
                                    title={val.title}
                                    columnId={index}
                                    orders={orders}
                                    setOrders={setOrders}
                                    setColumns={setColumns}
                                />
                            );
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <OrderColumn
                                    title={val.title}
                                    columnId={index}
                                    setOrders={setOrders}
                                    setColumns={setColumns}
                                />
                            );
                        }
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </DragDropContext>
    );
};

Schedule.propTypes = {
    orders: PropTypes.array
};

export default Schedule;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to sound glib, but essentially it means exactly what it says. `onDragEnd` is not a React component because it is not returning a `ReactElement` or some kind of JSX.  If you edited your blank return statements to return `<div>`'s (for all paths) it would be considered a component and work properly, but as of right now it's not returning anything.

Comment: But those 2 conditions, I want to cancel out and not do anything.  There has to be a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You could define the function within the component, where it would have access to the context.

Comment: so put onDragEnd inside Schedule?

Comment: I'm not totally sure on how your project is structured or if it may have any side effects, but it could certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and passing the context to that function will help solve your problem.

An example below:

```
const onDragEnd(result, context) => {
    // Adjust as necessary
}

const Schedule = () => {
    const context = useContext(ScheduleContext);
    const onDragEnd = useCallback((result) => onDragEnd(result, context), [context]);
    return <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
```

You can also either inline `onDragEnd` or pull out more and make a custom hook.

Comment: for some reason it wasn't recognizing `onCallback` as a function

Comment: You have to import it from React.

Comment: I just realized you wrote `onCallback`. The API is `useCallback`.